# Display: table-cell Working in Chrome not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

so from what I can tell it seems that display: table-cell isn't working for me in Firefox as it should. In Chrome and Safari it works fine.

Any ideas?

ETA: in the "services-section" there are two columns called "services-half". The left column is supposed to be 400px wide. Works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox that column is only 100 or so pixels wide. Think it has to do with display: table-cell in Firefox.

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Since people were saying they couldn't replicate the problem I've decided to upload screenshots from ScreenFly to show how the layout looks different between Chrome and Firefox.
[image: Chrom]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: could you specify what is the problem. And of course the code please

Comment: At first glance, your page looks the same to me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Avoid `display: table-cell` if you can help it, it's often abused when other layout techniques are better-supported.

Comment: @1l13v I edited the post to add more info.

Comment: @Maximiilian Laumeister Please check again, the "services-section" has very different layouts in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Dai So what else do you suggest. Using display: block and display: inline-block is not going to work here.

Comment: @lemonsevens15 still cannot see the problem. Your page is exactly the same in chrome and mozila

Comment: In Firefox on my computer, the site looks exactly like in your Chrome screenshot. What version of Firefox are you using, and are all of your extensions disabled? (Firefox 41 btw)

Comment: That's weird? I've added images.

Comment: Using Firefox 41.0 and all extensions are disabled. Checked on my desktop, laptop and tablet. All show broken in Firefox and fine in Chrome.

Comment: Just uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox. Still messed up. I don't know what you guys are talking about lol. Feel like you're trolling me because for the life of me I can't find a Firefox installation that works like you say it does.

Comment: Don't worry @lemonsevens15, you're not crazy - I'm seeing what you're seeing :)

Comment: @CupawnTae Lol, I'm mad I was sent on a wild goose chase. Anyways, thanks. Your fix works great.

Comment: Btw, there are some HTML errors, too (you have some unclosed elements there)...

Comment: @nevermind Thanks. Any you can point out in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem as suggested in comments is that you shouldn't be using a table layout for this. Table layouts are for laying out tabular data, which this isn't.

Browsers have a certain amount of flexibility when it comes to laying out tables as the spec is relatively loose, which accounts for the differences you're seeing on the different browsers. Once you use `table-cell` rendering, the browser can reapportion space according to its own algorithm.

I would strongly recommend using another layout mechanism such as flexbox, but if you're determined to stick with table layout, you can use `style="min-width:400px"` to fix your specific issue.

Using `position: relative` on a `table-cell` as you have on the right is also going to cause you issues, so you should also reconsider that combination.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I'm going to try to redo this with Flexbox and then check back in.

Comment: Flexbox works great! Knew I should of learned about this sooner. Thanks!